# Replace a gluster fs brick with a new server

Tags: debian, glusterfs

Important details:
We're running gluster 3.2.5 across 4 servers (two at each data center that replicate to the other two) all running debian squeeze (although if possible I would like the "replacement" to be running wheezy as I will format before I change roles).

Ok, so I have a bit of a situation at work. The previous sysadmin installed and started using GlusterFS to distribute our files across our two data centers. Well its time for upgrades of our systems, and he tied each gluster brick to the host name rather than an alias.

Essentially what I want to do is, replace the gluster brick with a different server. Essentially because the server we want to replace the brick with has similar specs currently, but the current brick can be upgraded more (so we want to change its role).

Problem is, I know very little about gluster, and from what I understand it is tied very closely to the name of the brick. Well the guy who set it up used the servers hostnames rather than an alias, and I've been told to "if in any way possible do not swap the hostnames of the two servers, as it will be very confusing in the future looking at old documentation".

So, in short, I need to replace a brick with another server, that has been setup using its host name.... does anyone have any advice?

I apologize if this post is a bit confusing... the whole thing is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Advice? sure, get someone in who knows what they're doing - seriously, not kidding, you sound well intentioned but you'll break something, get someone in who knows this stuff, sorry.

Comment: I agree that this needs careful planning as gluster is not so easy for these kind of operations. There is a replace-brick command in gluster, but from what I've read  on the mailing list it doesn't work properly in the last versions (maybe it's ok for 3.2.5 and you have backups). The important thing is that you backup before starting :)